# Is $p(x > a)$ for a discrete PDF necessarily linear?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We got these solutions to a class problem, and I'm having trouble seeing why the (b) is true: [problem solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBiwZ.png) (sorry it's not inline, not enough rep)

For example, let $\alpha_1 = 0.25, \alpha_2 = 0.5, \alpha_3 = 0.75$. This satisfies the constraint that $\alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \alpha_3$. Now, let $p(x = \alpha_1) = 0.25, p(x = \alpha_2) = 0.5, p(x = \alpha_3) = 0.25$.

Then,

\begin{equation*}
  p(x \geq \alpha) =
  \begin{cases}
    1    &  0     \leq \alpha \leq \alpha_1\\
    0.75 &  \alpha_1 < \alpha \leq \alpha_2\\
    0.25 &  \alpha_2 < \alpha \leq \alpha_3\\
    0    &  \alpha_3 < \alpha \leq  1
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Plotting this out, it's pretty clearly not linear...so I don't understand the solution's claim that this is a linear function of p. It definitely doesn't look convex. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{p}$ is a vector. I think linear in $\mathbf{p}$ just means that it can be expressed as a product of a matrix and $\mathbf{p}$, i.e. like $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{p}$. And $P(x\ge \alpha)$ indeed can be.